# shiny htmlwidget renders blank

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, htmlwidgets

I have the following shiny app.

## server.R

```
library(radarchart)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$radar <- renderChartJSRadar({
    scores <- data.frame("Label"=c("Communicator", "Data Wangler", "Programmer",
                                   "Technologist",  "Modeller", "Visualizer"),
                         "Rich" = c(9, 7, 4, 5, 3, 7),
                         "Andy" = c(7, 6, 6, 2, 6, 9),
                         "Aimee" = c(6, 5, 8, 4, 7, 6))
    
    chartJSRadar(scores, maxScale = 10, showToolTipLabel=TRUE)
    
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  
  
  titlePanel("RADARRRRR "),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10), width = 4
    ),
    mainPanel(
      chartJSRadarOutput("radar")
    )
  )
))
```

This app runs with no errors. no R console messages, no chrome console messages and a blank canvas for the plot.
I know the plotting library works because I can force it to display into Rstudio.
I have also checked to see if the chart.js is in the library and it seems fine.

Any help fixing or ideas for even starting to debug with no error messages are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "...and a blank canvas for the plot": an element with id `radar` is created but there's just nothing in it?

Comment: <canvas id="radar" class="chartJSRadar html-widget html-widget-output shiny-bound-output" width="908" height="3632" style="visibility: inherit; width: 1009px; height: 4036px;"></canvas>

Comment: oh, its huge. its just way off screen. you fixed it by making me type out my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: was just going to ask you if you'd scrolled down... :)

Comment: I don't know if i have enough reputation to select an answer but you're welcome to type one and i'll try and select it.

Comment: Done. I also made it seem like I could see into the future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your canvas in the page. I suspect it's just really huge and you need to scroll down a little to see it.